# How to determine when ScrollViewer started scrolling?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer

I'm using a Windows Phone 8.1 project and have a `ScrollViewer` in my XAML.

Is there an event which will fire when the ScrollViewer start scrolling? Or anyway to trigger code when ScrollViewer start scrolling?

Comment: There's no need to list tags in your title. I also removed the greeting from your post, since we all see who you are in your character sheet at the bottom. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles for more information about tags in titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ViewChanging` and `ViewChanged` events of `ScrollViewer`.

Note that these events will be called multiple times during a touch manipulation. You will need to rely on `IsIntermediate` (in `ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs`) or `IsInertial` (in `ScrollViewerViewChangingEventArgs`) to call your code accordingly.

---

**Update**

If you want to know when a touch happens immediately I'd give the `ScrollViewer`'s direct child, for example, a `StackPanel` a transparent background and then subscribe to its `PointerEntered` event.

Comment: I have tried them already, but they never fire immediately as I start touching screen.

Comment: But your question was asking when it starts scrolling? Or touching?

Comment: I am trying to say that it raise ViewChanging or ViewChanged in the middle of scrolling. But I want to know the event or way to trigger as immediately as scrolling start.